# How to implement grep in C++ so it works with pipes (stdin,etc.)?

Tags: c++, pipe

I want to implement grep for a Shell I'm doing in Windows (just for learning purpose).
I know that grep has the following syntax:

```
grep pattern files
```

So I can make a function like:

```
int grep(string stringToMatch, string fileName) // just one file
{
   // search file for stringToMatch
   // print line containing stringToMatch
}
```

My confusion is, how does grep supposed to work when I use a pipe like this:

```
ls | grep someword
```

I implemented "ls" to put all the output in a vector and return that, so I guess then my grep should search the vector for the results. So how should the correct grep function look ?  Do I need 2 grep functions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you implementing the UNIX Shell in C++?

Comment: I am not sure how much you want to implement but you can certainly use regular expression to implement string matching part in your grep function. refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcwwszd7(v=vs.80).aspx for regular expression

Comment: @rubenvb: i'm using boost to get familiar with it, so i thought to build a simple shell, using boost librabries. @llho: i thought i could use boost.regex, thank you.

Comment: ah, ok, academic purposes ftw! I'd go with [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to get the pattern matching done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to see how many command line arguments you've been passed. If there is only one then you assume that you're using stdin instead of a file.

In C++ this can be abstracted by using a reference to a `std::istream` in your function. Before you call the function you decide (and create) a `std::ifstream` if appropriate, or use `std::cin` otherwise.

Thus your function becomes:

```
int grep(string stringToMatch, std::istream& in) // just one file
{
   // search file for stringToMatch
   // print line containing stringToMatch
}
```

And you can use a conditional (using `argc` and `argv` in `main`) to do either:

```
grep(string, std::cin);
```

or

```
std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str());
grep(string, file);
```

Answer (score 5):

Read up on [UNIX filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29) or [here](http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/pipesfilters.html)

Unix filters communicate on standard input and standard output. I.e. the standard output of the first process is received on the standard input of the second process.

**Standard input and output are essentially binary/text streams**

This method can be chained. The shell is typically the party that manages the 
 - environment
 - start, monitoring and exit of processes
 - the interconnections

So 
  0. a user gives a command,e.g. ls
  1. the shell finds the command, creates a new process, connects stdin from the terminal and stdout from thte terminal, 
  2. waits for program execution
  3. sets environment with the result of the subprocess

If you say you have 'ls' output in a vector, I'm afraid that you are not really close to programming a shell in the true fashion

If you wanted to do a shell without all the idiosyncrasies of process management, pipes, redirections and whatnot, the most useful vehicle would be std::istream and std::ostream (or Boost IOStreams library).

A very very simple (really very dumb) version of grep could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static bool is_match(const std::string& text, const std::string& pattern)
{
    // FIXME TODO use actual (posix?) regex, boost regex, regex++ or whatnot
    return std::string::npos != text.find(pattern);
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    switch(argc)
    {
        case 0: case 1:
            std::cerr << "specify the pattern" << std::endl;
            return 254;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "not implemented" << std::endl;
            return 255;
    }
    const std::string pattern(argv[1]);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (is_match(line, argv[1]))
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Better examples exist [e.g. here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/example/grep/grep.cpp) but judging from the question I though this was the next informative step down the road ;)

Note also that Boost IOstreams library seems to contain [built-in support for pipelines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your post is very usefull, yes my ideea of grep was the same with your code..but I'm coding in windows, so I can't use unix filters.

Comment: There is precious little difference: console applications have stdin, stdout and stderr on windows. You'd be surprised how posix complete Win32 is out-of-the-box. So, yes you can have 'UNIX filters' (whatever that is) and they are done: Cygwin, UnxUtils, MingW etc. all provide complete shell environments on windows).

Comment: The most important difference is that CMD.EXE normally doesn't do 'real pipes' or 'real redirection' (it uses temp files instead of named pipes). Just don't use CMD.EXE :)

Comment: Well, using VS2010, I gues I am using cmd.exe :)

Comment: @sehe: That was true of MS-DOS command.com, but has *never* been true of cmd.exe. cmd.exe has used "real" pipes from the very beginning (not only back to Windows NT 3.1, but all the way back to OS/2 1.0, come to that).

Comment: @Jerry: informative, thanks @vBx: misguided. You are using windows, not CMD.EXE

Answer (score 2):

Your grep function should work on a `FILE *` (or the C++ equivalent). If you get a filename passed as an argument, open that file. If not, read from `stdin`.

Comment: using FILE * and more generally stdio.h in new C++ code is usually considered bad practice, unless there's a compelling reason otherwise, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @awoodland, "generally considered bad practice" by whom? You? You should try to be less vocally judgmental when there's little reason to.

Comment: for starters by the person who upvoted my comment and the [comp.lang.c++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.1) which is usually regarded as pretty authoritative.

Comment: sorry, it wasn't meant to sound vocally judgemental, but I do think there is a strong argument for suggesting "best practice" instead of legacy code to new programmers. It's up there with arrays vs std::vector, C++ style casts and std::string vs const char * on my list of bad practice that is accidentally encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use some library like [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) and compute the result of the pattern entered in your shell.

In the case of pipe, thats a feature of the shell and not grep. You can checkout [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess.html) and [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) libraries to implement it. Boost Asio supports many POSIX interprocess communication mechanisms.

Comment: My reading of the question was that the OP was asking "how can one function use either a file or stdin, but not need to know which?"

Comment: @awoodland: The title of the question asks for how to implement grep in c++, so I suggested couple of references.

Comment: @awoodland: yes, you are right, but the solution using boost.regex, might work too :)

Comment: thank you for your sugestion, i thought too about boost.regex

Answer (score 1):

When a command appears in such a syntax like you posted, it is supposed to read its input from the standard input. So, what you need to pass to your function isn't a string of the file name, but a open file descriptor or FILE* to a file, being it an file system resident file or the standard input.

Something like:

```
FILE *f;

if (argc == 3)
  f = fopen(argv[2], "r");
else
  f = stdin;

grep(argv[1], f);
```

Notice that if you do "ls | grep bar foo", grep will ignore the output of ls and will match "bar" in the file "foo". So, the above code reflects (with a lot of flaws embedded, and not fully, as grep can match multiple files) the behavior of grep.

Comment: using FILE * and more generally stdio.h in new C++ code is usually considered bad practice, unless there's a compelling reason otherwise, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @awoodland I'm a C programmer, sorry for this =D Although I saw the tag, I wish to expose my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

reopen **stdin** when user set second argument.

```
int grep(string stringToMatch, FILE *fp_in);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        freopen(argv[2], "r", stdin);
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Why reopen stdin when you are passing a FILE * around anyway? Why use FILE * in modern C++?